# how to replace lastindexof "," to the word "and" but avoid to replace "and" inside the open and close parenthesis in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how to replace last accurancy "," to the word "and" but avoid to replace "and" inside the open and close parenthesis in vb.net

sample:

A,A1,A2,A3,B,B1,B2,B3,C,C1,C2,C3

i want the output like this
A(A1,A2,A3),B(B1,B2,B3) and C(C1,C2,C3)

this is my code:
 Dim Strng As String = Me.CheckBox1.Text

```
    'now find the position of last appearing ","
    Dim comaposition As Integer
    comaposition = Strng.LastIndexOf(",") 'it is zero  based

    'if not found, it will return -1 and u can exit, no need to do the work
    If comaposition = "-1" Then

        Exit Sub
    End If

    'remove the comma
    Dim String_After_Removing_Comma As String
    String_After_Removing_Comma = Strng.Remove(comaposition, 1)

    'add "and" in the same position where comma was found
    Dim final_string As String
    final_string = String_After_Removing_Comma.Insert(comaposition, " and ")

    'show it on the textbox
    CheckBox1.Text = final_string
```

how can i do that any idea

Comment: It goes without saying, have you tried anything by yourself? If yes, post those codes

Comment: Are you able to successfully group the characters with `(` and `)`, I mean `A(A1,A2,A3),B(B1,B2,B3), C(C1,C2,C3)`

Comment: @Nobody, i just used his code and it doesn't do anything more than putting **"and"** at the end before **c3**

Comment: @Subaz I've made the solution for this, just want to know about OP's input. I know the posted codes don't do a damn thing as the output :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for you:

```
Dim test As String = "A,A1,A2,A3,B,B1,B2,B3,C,C1,C2,C3"

'this gets A,B,C 
Dim SingleChar As String() = test.Split(",").Where(Function(a) Not a.Any(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c))).ToArray()

'this gets rest of the string
Dim CharWithNumbers As String() = test.Split(",").Where(Function(a) a.Any(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c))).ToArray()

Dim StrFinal As String = ""

Dim diction = New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))()
Dim list = New List(Of String)()

'This will add similar strings found in "CharWithNumbers" based on 
'the characters in "SingleChar" to a list
For Each c As char In SingleChar
    list = New List(Of String)()
    diction.Add(c, list)
    For Each item As string In CharWithNumbers
        If item.Contains(c) Then
            list.Add(item)
        End If
    Next
Next

'grouping the list
For Each item  In diction
    StrFinal += item.Key + "(" + String.Join(",", item.Value) + "),"
Next

StrFinal = StrFinal.TrimEnd(","C) 'removes trailing ','

'to replace "," with "and"
Dim LastChar = SingleChar(SingleChar.Count() - 1)

StrFinal = StrFinal.Replace("," + LastChar + "(", " and " + LastChar + "(")

Console.WriteLine(StrFinal)
```

OUTPUT:

```
A(A1,A2,A3),B(B1,B2,B3) and C(C1,C2,C3)
```

**This is not optimized for performance**, but I don't think you would bother about it.

Check the output in [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/j4rVUx)

Comment: can you please explain this `Dim SingleChar As String() = test.Split(",").Where(Function(a) Not a.Any(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c))).ToArray()`

Comment: This will search for strings which does not have numbers in them. if you look closely you'll see a **Not**. `Dim CharWithNumbers ...` is just the same thing but **Without Not**, thus it will take rest of the string characters

Comment: let's say the string was "A,A1,A2,A3,B,B,B1,B2.B3". It would return A,B,B ?

Comment: Yes, my solution works for strings of the provided format

Comment: @Subaz  it would cause an error for his `diction` dictionary variable, as B would have already been added as a key. Needs some form of error handling for that scenario.

Comment: does your answer solve the part of the problem which says:  _"but avoid to replace "and" inside the open and close parenthesis in vb.net"_?  Your test string does not include any parentheses.

Comment: HI @Chris, you can check my solution in the fiddle link provided in the answer itself. It should format the output just as the op asked, for any input string provided in the format of the sample provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim arr() As String = Regex.Matches("A,A1,A2,A3,B,B1,B2,B3,C,C1,C2,C3", "(.)(,\1.+?)+").Cast(Of Match).Select(Function(M As Match) Regex.Replace(M.Value, "^(.),", "$1(") & ")").ToArray()
Dim withoutLastMatch(arr.Length - 2) As String
Array.Copy(arr, withoutLastMatch, arr.Length - 1)
Dim output As String = String.Join(",", withoutLastMatch) & " and " & arr(arr.Length - 1)
Console.WriteLine(output)
```

The output is:

> A(A1,A2,A3),B(B1,B2,B3) and C(C1,C2,C3)

Check solution at [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/BRoccQ)

Comment: I like your solution better than mine. Short and simple. Have my upvote :)

Comment: How about this my string = EnglishGrammar(Verb,Noun and Adjectives),Math(Algebra,Trigometric and Geometric), Science(Physics,Chemistry and Ecology)                                                                                                
                                                                                                                   
i want the output like this:  EnglishGrammar(Verb,Noun and Adjectives),Math(Algebra,Trigometric and Geometric) and Science(Physics,Chemistry and Ecology) i have no idea how to do that can you help for fix this?

Comment: i use this code  Dim arr() As String = Regex.Matches(ProvinceCagayan.Text, "(.)(,\1.+?)+").Cast(Of Match).Select(Function(M As Match) Regex.Replace(M.Value, "^(.),", "$1(") & ")").ToArray()
        Dim withoutLastMatch(arr.Length - 2) As String
        Array.Copy(arr, withoutLastMatch, arr.Length - 1)
        Dim output As String = String.Join(",", withoutLastMatch) & " and " & arr(arr.Length - 1)

        ProvinceCagayan.Text = output.ToString                                                 but i got error  "System.OverFlowException" how to fix it